# what type of data does string.length() return in c++?

Tags: c++, string, string-length, unsigned-integer

I am a beginner in C++. Today, I was trying to solve problem 139 on Leetcode, here is the pseudo-code:

```
for (string& word: wordDict) {
    int i=0;
    int word_len = word.length();
    cout << i - word.length() << endl;
    cout << i - word_len << endl;
}
```

And here is the result:

```
18446744073709551611
-5
18446744073709551613
-3
```

Why does the integer seem out of range if I don't declare the type of `word.length()` in front?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. That will (or *should*) indicate the problem. Clue: the `.length()` function returns a `size_t` type, which likely has higher (or equal, at least) rank than a plain `int`. And it is an *unsigned* type, for sure.

Comment: `std::string::size_type` a.k.a. `std::size_t` - See [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)

Comment: "what type of data does string.length() reutrn in c++?" - Why don't you just [look it up](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)?

Comment: `cout << typeid(decltype(word.length())).name() << "\n";` or if you use Boost `cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(decltype(word.length())).name()) << "\n";`

Comment: I can't recall it off the top of my head, but boost has a type library with pretty print capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the member function length is an unsigned integer type named like `size_type`.

As the type is unsigned then the expression

```
i - word.length()
```

also has an unsigned value because the rank of the type size_type (that usually corresponds to the type size_t) is not less than the rank of the type int.

You could write for example

```
i - ( int )word.length()
```

to use signed arithmetic.

Comment: I prefer using non-C-style casts: `i - static_cast<int>(word.length());`...